# Quit Electron from VueJs

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-vue

I am using [vue-cli-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder). So how I can quit the application from a button in vue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
// In your renderer process
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
const closeApp = document.getElementById('closeApp');
closeApp.addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('close-me')
});

// In your app main process
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('close-me', (evt, arg) => {
  app.quit()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

In your script tag you may create a button on your page and give it an event listener like:

```
window.close()
```

or

```
app.exit(0)
```